# UITabBarController height decreases everytime it's loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When I first load my application and log in. Everything is fine.

However when I log out, then log back in. The height of my view has been decreased. Here's a screenshot of the bug:

[image]

I havn't been able to find the cause of this. Making this quite a difficult question to ask help with as I can't specify the precise section of code causing the issue. But I'll try.

The problematic setup is like so:

I have a `containerViewController`, with 2 childViewControllers, a menu and a `UITabBarController`. The `UITabBarController` has 2 `UIViewControllers`.

To better explain it, here's a visual representation.

```
_______________________

App Start -> 

NavigationController(rootViewController LandingPageVC)

   LandingPageVC -> push -> SignInVC(this is where I login from)

   SignInVC -> push -> ContainerViewController(this has my UITabBarController and my menu)

   ContainerViewController (sets up my menuTabBarController and menu)

        menuTabBarController (this tabBarController is used to switch out my content from the menu)

        SidePanelViewController (this is my menu)

   ContainerViewController -> push(signing out) -> LandingPageVC

_______________________
```

Here's how I push the containerViewController when a successful login is called.

```
let mainTableViewController = ContainerViewController()
mainTableViewController.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
navigationController!.pushViewController(mainTableViewController, animated: true)
menuEnabled = true
```

here's the function called from the `containerViewController` I use to log out.

```
func signOut() {

    // Set up the landing page as the main viewcontroller again.
    let mainTableViewController = LandingPageVC()
    mainTableViewController.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    mainTableViewController.skipView = false
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(mainTableViewController, animated: true)

    // Disable menu access
    menuEnabled = false
}
```

by printing the height of ContainerViewController and menuTabBarController, I found that it is the UITabBarController's height that's decreasing and not the ContainerViewController.

Here's the code that has to do with the UITabBarController

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

let menuTabBarController = UITabBarController()

var menuButton = UIBarButtonItem()

var menuEnabled = false

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, CenterViewControllerDelegate, SidePanelViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func needsSignOut(sender: SidePanelViewController) {
        // toggling left panel
        self.toggleLeftPanel()
        // signing out
        self.signOut()
    }


  var centerViewController: UITabBarController!

  var leftViewController: SidePanelViewController?

  let centerPanelExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 60

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menuTabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true

    menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "toggleLeftPanel")
    if let font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: 20) {
        menuButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton

    //let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let suggestionsVC = SuggestionsViewController()
    let testVC = detaiLSuggestion_VC()
    let controllers = [suggestionsVC,testVC]

    menuTabBarController.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: false)

    centerViewController = menuTabBarController
    view.addSubview(menuTabBarController.view)
    addChildViewController(menuTabBarController)

    //centerNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
  }

  // MARK: CenterViewController delegate methods

  func toggleLeftPanel() {

    let notAlreadyExpanded = (currentState != .LeftPanelExpanded)

    if notAlreadyExpanded {
        addLeftPanelViewController()
    }

    animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: notAlreadyExpanded)

  }

  func collapseSidePanels() {
    switch (currentState) {
    case .LeftPanelExpanded:
      toggleLeftPanel()
    default:
      break
    }
  }

  func addLeftPanelViewController() {
    if (leftViewController == nil) {
        leftViewController = SidePanelViewController()
        leftViewController!.delegate = self

        addChildSidePanelController(leftViewController!)
    }
  }

  func addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: SidePanelViewController) {

    view.insertSubview(sidePanelController.view, atIndex: 0)

    addChildViewController(sidePanelController)
    sidePanelController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
  }

  func animateLeftPanel(#shouldExpand: Bool) {
    if (shouldExpand) {
      currentState = .LeftPanelExpanded

        animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGRectGetWidth(centerViewController.view.frame) - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
    } else {
      animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { finished in
        self.currentState = .BothCollapsed

        self.leftViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.leftViewController = nil;
      }
    }
  }


  func animateCenterPanelXPosition(#targetPosition: CGFloat, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.centerViewController.view.frame.origin.x = targetPosition
      }, completion: completion)
  }
```

Any help deducing where this is coming from or how I can go about fixing it would be greatly appreciated! And again I apologize for the dumb of code. I'll update it further if I am able to rule out parts of it.

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what you're trying to do. Why do you have 3 different tab bar controllers, menuTabBarController, menuTabBarController, and centerViewController? If you're trying to follow something like the setup I talked about in the answer to another of your questions, there should only be 1 tab bar controller.

Comment: What I had in mind was something like this updated version of my test app, http://jmp.sh/d07hcHp This is still using the storyboard to do the setup, but you should let me know if this is the functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for the replies again. I only have (or rather use) one `UITabBarController` the menuTabBarController. I'm setting `CenterViewController = menuTabBarController` as for the `centerTabBarController` that was a test one I forgot to remove in my paste. Anyhow, I looked at your test app. But it doesn't seem to have another viewController. My menu system works perfectly fine now. However when I push off my `containerViewController` and push it back. The menuTabBarController is loaded again, and for some reason loaded with a smaller frame height. That's the problem I'm currently having

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to have another view controller"? Do you mean something equivalent to your login controller? When you log out you push to LandingPageVC, is that a new controller, different from the login one?

Comment: @rdelmar yes. My app starts with a `UINavigationController` which root viewcontroller is the `loginViewController`. From there it pushes to the `ContainerViewController` (with it's 2 `childViewControllers`). Then I push from the `ContainerViewController` back to the `LandingPageViewController`. However when I log in again. The height of my `UITabBarController` isn't the full height of my screen. (it gets smaller every time I log out and back in.) - the test app you link you starts in a ContainerViewController. It doesn't push to and out of the `ContainerViewController`. (which is my problem).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74678/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-mark-l).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rdelmar found a solution for me in chat.

The problem was fixed by specifying the `menuTabBarController.view.frame` like so:

```
menuTabBarController.view.frame = self.view.frame
```